# Macro-average ROC curve not looking right

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, roc

I am performing a 10-fold Cross-validation on imbalance datasets with small n examples and large p attributes. I am plotting ROC curves by merging predicted probabilities obtained by testing on each k fold. The code below performs a CV on a multi-class dataset. Where during each iteration, k fold is used as test and the k-1 folds as training.

EDIT: I have created a [GitHub_repository](https://github.com/EdoT99/Issue)
storing the whole code and a toy dataset (modified 'Iris' dataset) for simplicity. Have fun!

Code below:

```
def cross_validation(X,Y,n_splits,model,kernel):
    

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits= n_splits, random_state=8, shuffle=True)
skf.get_n_splits(X,Y)  #X is (n_samples; n_features) y (target variable)

list_predict_prob_KDE, list_predict_prob_origi, list_predict_SMOTE = [], [], []   # initilize empty lists for probabilities
list_acc_ori, list_acc_smote, list_acc_kde = [], [], []
lst_y_test_labels = []
lst_X_test = []

for j,(train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X,Y)):     #iterate over the number of splits, returns indexes of the train and test set
    
        x_train_fold, x_test_fold = X[train_index], X[test_index]      #selected data for train and test in j-fold
        y_train_fold, y_test_fold = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]      #selected targets
        
        print('\n')
        print('ITERATION --> ',j)
        print('Raw training data: ',x_train_fold.shape)
        print('Raw training labels: ',y_train_fold.shape)
        print('Testing data: ',x_test_fold.shape)

    
    # 1) STEP
    #call the method OversampKDE on the training partitioning, which
        #- given a list of class examples, oversamples the minority classes
        x1_fold,y1_fold= oversamp_KDE_definitive(x_train_fold,y_train_fold,kernel)
    #call the method OversampSMOTE on the training partitioning
        x2_fold,y2_fold = oversamp_SMOTE_definitive(x_train_fold,y_train_fold)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 2) STEP
    #fit model on augmented dataset KDE
        
        model.fit(x1_fold,y1_fold)
        # --> test model on test fold; append predict_proba
        
        y_proba_kde = model.predict_proba(x_test_fold)
        y_pred_kde = model.predict(x_test_fold)
        acc_kde = accuracy_score(y_test_fold,y_pred_kde)

        list_acc_kde.append(acc_kde)
        list_predict_prob_KDE.append(y_proba_kde)
        #----------------------------
        #fit model on augmented training SMOTE
        model.fit(x2_fold,y2_fold)
        # test --< model on test fold ; append predict_proba
       
        y_proba_smote = model.predict_proba(x_test_fold)
        y_pred_smote = model.predict(x_test_fold)
        acc_smote = accuracy_score(y_test_fold,y_pred_smote)

        list_acc_smote.append(acc_smote)
        list_predict_SMOTE.append(y_proba_smote)
        #-----------------------------------
        #fit model on train set (normal)
        
        model.fit(x_train_fold,y_train_fold)

        y_proba = model.predict_proba(x_test_fold)
        y_pred= model.predict(x_test_fold)
        acc_ori= accuracy_score(y_test_fold,y_pred)

        list_acc_ori.append(acc_ori)
        list_predict_prob_origi.append(y_proba)
        #-------------------------------------
        # 3) STEP
        # append Y_test labels to lst_y_test_labels
        lst_y_test_labels.append(y_test_fold)

#averaged accuracies over k-folds
d_acc = {'model_original' : mean(list_acc_ori),'model_smote':mean(list_acc_smote),'model_kde':mean(list_acc_kde)}
#aggregating k-fold probability estimates
d_proba = {'model_original':np.concatenate(list_predict_prob_origi,axis = 0),'model_smote':np.concatenate(list_predict_SMOTE,axis = 0),'model_kde':np.concatenate(list_predict_prob_KDE,axis = 0)}  
y_test_labels = np.concatenate(lst_y_test_labels, axis = 0)

return y_test_labels, d_probabilities, d_acc
```

Since the multi-class scenario, I am comparing micro and macro averages methods from sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#roc-curve-using-the-ovr-macro-average.
However, macro-averaged ROC curves are displaying strange behavior since are not starting from (0,0)
[image]

This behavior is not shown in micro-averaged ROC curves, nor on ROC curves from binary datasets obtained from the same CV method above. What could be the reason?

[image]

At the end of the Cross Validation, I concatenate lists of predicted probabilities for each model.

```
d_probabilities = {'model_original':np.concatenate(list_predict_prob_origi,axis 
 = 0),'model_smote':np.concatenate(list_predict_SMOTE,axis 
 =0),'model_kde':np.concatenate(list_predict_prob_KDE,axis = 0)}  
y_test_labels = np.concatenate(lst_y_test_labels, axis = 0)
```

A Vector of predicted probabilities from a Random Forest Classifier looks like this one:

```
Predicted scores : [[0.82 0.09 0.05 0.   0.04]
                   [0.94 0.01 0.   0.04 0.01]
                   [0.98 0.01 0.01 0.   0.  ]
                   [0.81 0.12 0.04 0.01 0.02]
                   [0.88 0.08 0.02 0.01 0.01]
                   [0.1  0.74 0.06 0.04 0.06]
                   [0.06 0.77 0.11 0.02 0.04]
                   [0.04 0.79 0.04 0.02 0.11]
                   [0.03 0.12 0.73 0.11 0.01]
                   [0.06 0.14 0.7  0.09 0.01]
                   [0.03 0.03 0.86 0.06 0.02]
                   [0.06 0.1  0.05 0.72 0.07]
                   [0.15 0.35 0.01 0.09 0.4 ]
                   [0.9  0.04 0.02 0.   0.04]
                   [0.94 0.05 0.   0.01 0.  ]
                   [0.9  0.06 0.04 0.   0.  ]
                   [0.67 0.16 0.1  0.03 0.04]
                   [0.07 0.5  0.03 0.01 0.39]]



n_classes = len(np.unique(y_test))
y_test_binarize = label_binarize(y_test, classes=np.arange(n_classes))
scores = {}
for model_name, model_proba in d_probabilities.items():  
   y_pred = model_proba
   scores[model_name] = model_proba

fpr ,tpr ,roc_auc ,thresholds = dict(), dict(), dict() ,dict() 
# micro-average
for i in range(n_classes):
  fpr[i], tpr[i], thresholds[i] = roc_curve(y_test_binarize[:, i], y_pred[:, i], drop_intermediate=False)
  roc_auc[i] = metrics.auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test_binarize.ravel(), y_pred.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = metrics.auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
#aggregates all false positive rates

all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))
#fpr_grid = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 1000)

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
#mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(fpr_grid)
for i in range(n_classes):
  mean_tpr += np.interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])
# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes
fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = metrics.auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

# storing average-micro fpr, tpr, auc for each method (original,smote,kde)
row_micro = {'Classifier': model_name, 'fpr': fpr['micro'],'tpr':tpr['micro'],'auc':roc_auc['micro']}
#row_micro = {'Classifier': model_name, 'fpr': fpr['micro'],'tpr':tpr['micro'],'auc':roc_auc['micro']}
table_multi_micro.loc[len(table_multi_micro)] = row_micro

# storing average-macro fpr, tpr, auc for each method (original,smote,kde)
row_macro = {'Classifier': model_name,'fpr':fpr['macro'],'tpr':tpr['macro'],'auc':roc_auc['macro']}
#row_macro = {'Classifier': model_name,'fpr':fpr['macro'],'tpr':tpr['macro'],'auc':roc_auc['macro']}
table_multi_macro.loc[len(table_multi_macro)] = row_macro
```

Comment: Without your data it's hard to say.  As you step through your code, when do you stop having a 0 at the beginning (end?) of the lists?

Comment: Those predicted "probabilities" aren't very nuanced, and I don't understand how they could lead to those ROC curves.  But I don't think that should interfere with getting (0,0) on the plot...

Comment: Those predicted probabilities were from another classifier (NB). Unfortunately, providing a dataset for reproducibility seems impractical. Or there is a way?

Comment: If you can shrink the predictions to something like what you've already included, with the corresponding true values, while still reproducing the issue, then that could be included directly here.  Or if you can reproduce the issue with a sklearn dataset, that's easy enough to grab.  Otherwise, if it's really dependent on your full data, sharing that in a github repo may work. // We may be able to help without that, if you can provide some toy versions of the intermediate arrays: what do `fpr` and `tpr` look like for some of your models, then how does the `np.interp` result look?

Comment: It's indeed a good idea!, I have created a GitHub repository for testing the issue. You can find a sample script.py and a toy dataset!